# Database best normalization

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have these tables in my database:

```
bookings(id,lessons_id,users_id)
lessons(id,name,date,max_enrollments,enrollments)
permits(id,user_id,used_entries,entries)
```

Everytime I insert a new record in bookings the

```
lessons.enrollments increments by +1 
permits.used_entries -1 where user_id eq Auth()->id
permits.entries increments by +1
```

I already have done three funx that do this in my PHP code but the prb is to do it in an automatic way! Can somebody give me some suggestions?

Comment: You should be able to do this using triggers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen gimme a small example

Comment: I think the problem you're encountering is the `used_entries` is a calculated field. Instead of storing a value which changes, you should store something like `max_entries`. Then anywhere in your app that you want to display the used entries you display `max_entries - count(bookings)` (or similar). Often difficulty normalizing data is the result of attempting to store values that should be calculated.

Comment: @stevendesu thanks its true I do have a max_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how far along you are in application development or how easy it is to change your schema, but if it's possible you should try to get your database into normal form. A handy tip to get your database into normal form is to remember this saying:

> I solemnly swear to provide a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key - so help me, Codd

- **Provide a fact about the key**: This means that each field in your database should provide **ONE** fact. Instead of a "phone numbers" field (if a user could have multiple phone numbers) you should have a "phone numbers" **table** with a "user_id" and "phone number" (singular). This way you don't ever store two facts (two phone numbers) in a single field
- **The whole key**: This ensures that your database doesn't have conflated or duplicated data. Suppose your have a table of images, and for each image you store the image name (e.g. "kittens"), the image type (e.g. "jpeg"), and whether or not it support transparency (e.g. "false"). In this case, to uniquely identify one image you need to know its name **and** its type. "kittens.jpg" is different from "kittens.png". However whether or not the image supports transparency can be determined by its type (PNG supports transparency, JPEG does not) -- but does **NOT** depend on its name. This means every JPEG in your table will have this value set to `false`... **hopefully**. But what happens if one JPEG sets this to true? Do you trust that row of the database? To solve this, you create a separate table of "image types" then the images table will simply reference one of the types in the "image types" table.
- **And nothing but the key**: Any field in the table should depend **only** on the key, and not on anything else. Something like "enrollments remaining" would depend on the number of "max enrollments". Just as the previous rule prevented confusingly invalid data across multiple rows (like one JPEG saying it supported transparency and another saying it did not), this rule prevents confusingly invalid data **within a single row**. If you had 5 enrollments remaining but 3 max enrollments, that would make no sense!

Judging from how you modify the fields when a booking is created, I assume your logic is something like the following:

- Your app consists of "users" and "lessons"
- A "user" is given a certain number of "permits"
- In order to sign up for a "lesson", a user must expend one of his "permits"
- A user cannot sign up for a "lesson" if the lesson has already reached is maximum number of users
- Multiple users can sign up for the same lesson, and a user can sign up for multiple lessons (assuming he has enough permits)

In this case, the number of permits a user has is a fact about the user. So I would modify your schema like so:

```
users(id, name, permits)
lessons(id, name, date, max_users)
bookings(user_id, lesson_id)
```

This is a minimal schema that describes the system above. Now in your code when a user attempts to make a booking you must check two things:

```
(count(bookings) where lesson_id = lesson.id) < lesson.max_users
(count(bookings) where user_id = user.id) < user.permits
```

If both of these check out, you allow the booking to go through. When you create the booking -- **that's all you need to do**. Because the database is in normal form, you don't need to edit any fields or update any values. You just create the booking and you're done!

Now a quick note on performance: 99% of the time, normal form is the right way to go. However normal form often trades performance for data integrity. If you have millions of lessons and millions of users, you may find that running the `count(bookings) where lesson_id = lesson.id` query takes **too long**. In this case, you may need to *denormalize* your data.

Denormalization allows you to improve performance at the cost of making your app **way** more complex. It should always be the **absolute last** thing you do to improve performance - because app complexity is rarely worth it. Before you denormalize the data, make sure you've done everything in your power to get the most out of indexing, caches, etc.

### Update: A Query to Meet Your Needs

You requested a query to:

> get all lessons where this user [has] entered

I may have misunderstood this original request since you later said that you wanted all the lessons that **aren't** booked for the user. You also posted some code that looks like you're using Laravel. I'll try to put together two chunks of Laravel code for you -- one for each of these questions:

```
// All lessons the user *has* booked
$lessons = DB::table("Bookings")
               ->join("Lessons", "Bookings.lesson_id", "=", "Lessons.id")
               ->where("Bookings.user_id", "=", Auth::user()->id);

// All lessons the user *has not* booked
$lessons = DB::table("Lessons")
               ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                   $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                         ->from("Bookings")
                         ->where("user_id", "=", Auth::user()->id);
               });
```

Although I believe this will work, you may find it easier to take advantage of Laravel's built-in relations.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function lessons() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Lesson", "Bookings");
    }
}
class Lesson extends Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\User", "Bookings");
    }
}
```

Given these relations you can simplify both queries:

```
$lessons = \App\Lesson::whereHas("users", function($query) {
    $query->where("user_id", "=", Auth::user()->id);
});
$lessons = \App\Lesson::whereDoesntHave("users", function($query) {
    $query->where("user_id", "=", Auth::user()->id);
});
```

**Disclaimer:** I haven't tested any of the above queries, but if nothing else they should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: +10 mate only for the time taken to write all this,super

Comment: one last question how can I get  all lessons where this user hast entered ,I have done smth like this but apperently is wrong`code SELECT lessons.*
from lessons
left join bookings
on lessons.id =bookings.lessons_id
WHERE lessons.date > NOW()
and bookings.user_id <> 2 `

Comment: It's easiest to start with the `bookings` table: `SELECT lessons.* FROM bookings LEFT JOIN lessons ON bookings.lesson_id = lessons.id WHERE bookings.user_id = ...`

Comment: nope it still doest give me all the lessons that arent book from this user

Comment: `code $lesson = DB::table("Lessons")->select('*')->whereNotIn('id',function($query) {
   $query->select('lessons_id')->from('bookings');
  })
  // ->where("bookings.user_id",'<>','Auth()->id')
  ->where('lessons.date', '>', Carbon::now())
  ->where('max_enrollments','>','enrollments')
  ->get(); ` I did smth like this but still I have also to remove this users entries couse like the query above I remove all the lessons that are booked